# optuna lightgbm integration runs endlessly

Tags: python, machine-learning, lightgbm, optuna

I'm using `optuna.integration.lightgbm.train` and adapting [this](https://github.com/optuna/optuna-examples/blob/main/lightgbm/lightgbm_tuner_simple.py) example with my data, which has about 1M rows in the training set and 700K in the validation set.

But I have been waiting for more than 20 hours and the process does not finish after a while, I notice It has started to overfit since the validation metric (ROC AUC) is very close to.999

Sample code:

```
params = {
    "objective": "binary",
    "metric": "auc",
    "verbosity":1,
    "boosting_type": "gbdt",
}

model = lgb.train(
    params,
    dtrain,
    valid_sets=[dtrain, dval],
    callbacks=[early_stopping(3), log_evaluation(3)],
    show_progress_bar = True,
    time_budget = 1,
    early_stopping_rounds = 2
)
```

How can I speed up this and/or set the number of rounds it should run?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble too.  Some suggestions: 1) add a pruner to callbacks something like:

```
pruning_callback = optuna.integration.LightGBMPruningCallback( trial, metric = "binary_logloss", valid_name = "valid_0" )
lgb.train( 
, callbacks = [ pruning_callback, early_stopping(100), log_evaluation(100 )]
)
```

2. don't use lgb.train() but instead use

```
model = LGBMClassifier( objective="binary", **param_grid, n_jobs = -1 )
model.fit()
```

Also, I can't get early_stopping( min_delta = 0.01 ) to work. ( parameter not recognized ) but this would help ( if I got it working )